# Finding the conjugates, why can they argue this way?(exercise)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

In one exercise I am supposed to find the conjugate of $\sqrt{2}+i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I found the answer by finding irr$( \sqrt{2}+i,\mathbb{Q})$, and then solving the polynomial finding all the roots(this is the definition of conjugates), this gave the correct answer, but in the solutions manual, they use a trick I do not understand.

They say that:

The conjugate are $\sqrt{2}+i,\sqrt{2}-i,-\sqrt{2}+i,-\sqrt{2}-i$. This is clear beacuse $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i)=(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))(i)$.

Can someone say how this is clear and why it follows from the fact that: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i)=(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))(i)$?

Comment: Have you also seen the fact that all conjugates are obtained as the image of $(2+i)$ under all field homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Q}(2+i) \to \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I have this theorem which seems close: Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over a field F. Every isomophism mapping $F(\alpha)$ onto a subfield of $\overline{F}$ keeping F fixed, maps $\alpha$ onto a conjugate. Conversely, for each conjugate of $\alpha$ over F, there exists exactly one isomorphism of $F(\alpha)$ onto a subfield of $\overline{F}$ mapping $\alpha$ onto the conjugate and keeping F fixed. Maybe it follows from this in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you mention in your comments, the conjugates of $(\sqrt{2}+i)$ can be computed if we knew the image of $(\sqrt{2}+i)$ under every homomorphism
$$
\varphi : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i) \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}
$$
Since
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(i)
$$
we need to determine $\varphi(i)$ and $\varphi(\sqrt{2})$. However, since $\varphi$ is a field homomorphism
$$
\varphi(\sqrt{2})^2 = \varphi(2) = 2
$$
since any field homomorphism must fix $\mathbb{Q}$ (this takes a short proof). However, $2$ has exactly 2 square roots in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \subset \mathbb{C}$, so
$$
\varphi(\sqrt{2}) = \pm \sqrt{2}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\varphi(i) = \pm i
$$
and so the list of possible conjugates is
$$
\{\pm\sqrt{2}\pm i\}
$$
To prove that each of these is, in fact, a conjugate of $(\sqrt{2}+i)$, you need the fact that the number of such homomorphisms is precisely equal to the degree
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i):\mathbb{Q}]
$$
My answer is long enough already, so let me know if this helps and if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, I have just two questions. I get that it is enough to find every isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i)$, but why does it then follow that it is enough to find the images of $\sqrt{2}$ and i alone?, I mean why does the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i)=(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))(i)$, allow us to decompose our work in $\sqrt{2}$ and i alone? And to the last part, I get that the degree is four(by calculating the irreducible polynomial), but is it so that if the degree is 4, we can only have 4 conjugates?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(i)$ we can write $\varphi(\sqrt{2}+i) = \varphi(\sqrt{2}) + \varphi(i)$. And yes, if the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ is 4, then $\alpha$ has *exactly* 4 conjugates.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one more quick if you have time. Is it hard to show that the degree of en element equals to number of conjugates?

Comment: Not really. You need the fact that if $\varphi$ is such a field homomorphism, then $\alpha$ and $\varphi(\alpha)$ have the same minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2+i)$.  If you square $\sqrt{2}+i$ you get $1+2\sqrt2i$.  Thus $\sqrt{2}i\in F$.  Multiply this by $\sqrt2+i$ and you get $2i-\sqrt2\in F$.  Add $\sqrt2+i$ and you get $3i\in F$ thus $i\in F$.  Thus subtracting $i$ from $\sqrt{2}+i$ you get $\sqrt2\in F$.

Thus both $i$ and $\sqrt2$ are in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2+i)$

Comment: Thank you, but this I actually got, that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i)=(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))(i)$, it is how the conclusion follows from this that I do not get.

Comment: Well you know that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,i)$ is Galois since it's just two degree two extensions.  So you know the Galois group is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.  The automorphisms are determined by $\sqrt2\mapsto\pm\sqrt2$ and $i\mapsto\pm i$.  Since an automorphism must take roots of the polynomial to itself, it's clear that those are the four conjugates.